# Marshal.SizeOf error in computing size

Tags: c#, marshalling, structure, sizeof

i have a structure

```
 public struct SERVER_USB_DEVICE
        {
            USB_HWID usbHWID;
            byte status;
            bool bExcludeDevice;
            bool bSharedManually;
            ulong ulDeviceId;
            ulong ulClientAddr;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 256)]
            string usbDeviceDescr;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 256)]
            string locationInfo;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 256)]
            string nickName;
        }
```

i am getting following error

> System.ArgumentException was unhandled
>   Message="Type 'SERVER_USB_DEVICE'
>   cannot be marshaled as an unmanaged
>   structure; no meaningful size or
>   offset can be computed."

at following line

```
Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(USBOverNetWrapper.FT_SERVER_USB_DEVICE));
```

what is wrong in the code?

Abdul Khaliq

Comment: Show us the attribute with your struct.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> When `MarshalAsAttribute.Value` is set to `ByValArray`, the `SizeConst` must be set to indicate the number of elements in the array. **The `ArraySubType` field can optionally contain the `UnmanagedType` of the array elements when it is necessary to differentiate among string types.**

However I recommend you use this one instead:

> **`ByValTStr`**: Used for in-line, fixed-length character arrays that appear within a structure. The character type used with `ByValTStr` is determined by the  `System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet` argument of the  `System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute` applied to the containing structure. Always use the `MarshalAsAttribute.SizeConst` field to indicate the size of the array.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
// OR [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct SERVER_USB_DEVICE
{
    USB_HWID usbHWID;
    byte status;
    bool bExcludeDevice;
    bool bSharedManually;
    ulong ulDeviceId;
    ulong ulClientAddr;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
    string usbDeviceDescr;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
    string locationInfo;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
    string nickName;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
     public struct SERVER_USB_DEVICE{
         ....
     }
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5s4920fa.aspx