# Check if a GUI model has changed; comparing two GUI models

Tags: c#

I have the following scenario.

I have a complex Model (contains many objects, non-primitive data types). Through GUI i allow users to edit this model.

When the EDIT button is clicked i create a clone of the current model which the users modify until they press "Save" or "Discard".

I need to know if the cloned model has been changed and if its data has changed compared to the original one. Which would be the best way to check if the user changed any property of the model.

I'm thinking of two options here:

1. Override Equals and GetHashCode and implement IEquatable interface for each class of objects part of the model (would be a lot of work to do in this case).
2. Use a dirty flag.
3. I saw some implementations that INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

I don't consider Options 2 and 3 as valid options  because the user may modify one property and then set it back to the original value.(so the model isn't really changed).

Are there any other posibliies?

Thanks,

Dan

Comment: I know you asked for the best way, but if you wanted a hacky but quick solution, if all the objects are serializable you could serialize the original and the clone and compare the resulting string. I think the right way would be to implement `IEquatable` and `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and every time a property changes, compare it to check if it's different from the original.

Comment: Lemme ask you another thing: which version of .NET Framework and C# are you using?

Comment: @ConradClark I'm using .NEt framework 4.5 Visual studio 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an option, assuming your Model is Serializable (below method found in [Convert any object to a byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865104/convert-any-object-to-a-byte))

```
byte[] ObjectToByteArray(Object obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
        return new byte[]{};
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

Then, if your model is really huge and it can hurt performance, and you are able to use unsafe code, use this comparer i found here [Comparing two byte arrays in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43289/comparing-two-byte-arrays-in-net)

```
static unsafe bool UnsafeCompare(byte[] a1, byte[] a2)
    {
        if (a1 == null || a2 == null || a1.Length != a2.Length)
            return false;
        fixed (byte* p1 = a1, p2 = a2)
        {
            byte* x1 = p1, x2 = p2;
            int l = a1.Length;
            for (int i = 0; i < l / 8; i++, x1 += 8, x2 += 8)
                if (*((long*)x1) != *((long*)x2)) return false;
            if ((l & 4) != 0) { if (*((int*)x1) != *((int*)x2)) return false; x1 += 4; x2 += 4; }
            if ((l & 2) != 0) { if (*((short*)x1) != *((short*)x2)) return false; x1 += 2; x2 += 2; }
            if ((l & 1) != 0) if (*((byte*)x1) != *((byte*)x2)) return false;
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Otherwise, you can use the simpler but slower (found in the same question)

```
static bool ByteArrayCompare(byte[] a1, byte[] a2) 
{
    IStructuralEquatable eqa1 = a1;
    return eqa1.Equals(a2, StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer);
}
```

Here's a model to use in an example:

```
    [Serializable]
    class House
    {
        public Size Size{get;set;}
    }

    [Serializable]
    class Size
    {
        public double Width { get; set; }
        public double Length { get; set; }
        public double Height { get; set; }
    }
```

Then compare your object:

```
House house = new House()
{
    Size = new Size()
    {
        Width = 10
    }
};
House house2 = new House()
{
     Size = new Size()
     {
        Width = 20
     }
};
House equal = new House()
{
    Size = new Size()
    {
        Width = 10
    }
};

Debug.Assert(UnsafeCompare(ObjectToByteArray(house), ObjectToByteArray(equal)));
Debug.Assert(!UnsafeCompare(ObjectToByteArray(house), ObjectToByteArray(house2)));

Debug.Assert(ByteArrayCompare(ObjectToByteArray(house), ObjectToByteArray(equal)));
Debug.Assert(!ByteArrayCompare(ObjectToByteArray(house), ObjectToByteArray(house2)));
```