# C# byte array doesn't allocate correctly

Tags: c#, serialization, allocation

[image: Screenshot of weird problem]

I'm trying to serialize an object in C#.  I got the object size and saved it in a variable, size1 on line 207 in above screenshot.  Size1 has a value of 160.  Then I used size1 to allocate an array of bytes called buf in line 210.  Buf comes out to be a 2 byte array!  How can this be?!

Comment: Try to post your code here instead of printing the image!!

Comment: At least what "line 210" is, is very obvious :P

Comment: How do you know size1 has a value of 160?

Comment: The image also shows the values of local variables during runtime.  As it is the runtime behavior that I want to illustrate, the image is appropriate.  Also, no one is likely to believe me when I say byte[] buf = new byte[size1] results in buf having 2 bytes despite size1 has a value of 160!  The image of runtime behaviors makes my case.

Comment: The image would be appropriate _if_ you include some sample source code that we can copy into our own IDEs and try it for ourselves.

Comment: What line is the program stopped at in the image

Comment: The program throws an exception a few lines down when I used buf and it is not as long as expected.  But that is not the real problem, which is why the allocated buf has a different length than it should be, especially when the allocation is done correctly, as far as I know.

Comment: And forgot to add, this problem is repeatable (not a one-off thing).  size1 is always 160, buf is always 2 bytes, and buf2 is always 160 bytes, for all runs on my machine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is here

```
byte[] buf = new byte[size1];
byte[] buf2 = new byte[16];
buf = b.ReadBytes(...); //<----
```

You are replacing `buf` with the result of `ReadBytes`. That throws away your original array and replaces it with the array that was returned from `ReadBytes` (which in your case was a two byte array)

Comment: Exactly! Can't believe I commit a classic newbie mistake, which is the values of the local variables as shown in the debug window are the state of the program at the point the program stops/breaks, not some arbitrary lines before the break point.  I still have to figure out the problem with b.ReadBytes(...) but at least I will be going down the correct alley.  Thanks Scott!

Answer (score 4):

ReadBytes() returns a `byte[]`. When you write

```
buf = b.ReadBytes(Marshal.SizeOf(firstRecord));
```

then `buf` points at a completely different `byte[]` that equals whatever `b.ReadBytes()` returned.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to convert some object into a byte array, this answer may help.
[Convert any object to a byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865104/convert-any-object-to-a-byte)