# Convert object parameter to byte[] type in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have this object and want to convert it to `byte[]`

```
 var b =  new ObjectParameter("historyversion", typeof(string));
```

How can I do that? `b` must convert to `byte[]` in asp.net

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert any object to a byte\[\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865104/convert-any-object-to-a-byte)

Comment: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472906/converting-a-string-to-byte-array