# Is Serialization the same as GetBytes?

Tags: .net

Java provides a mechanism, called object serialization where an object can be represented as a sequence of bytes.

Found this on google. I use .Net to send packets using a socket connection. I use `Encoding.Default.GetBytes()`.

Serialization is confusing, what is the difference of it to GetBytes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `GetBytes()` just converts a *`string`* to its binary represenation using the asked *encoding*. So it does serialize, but it is very specific to strings.

When you want to serialize *any* object to bytes, you could use the [`BinaryFormatter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter(v=vs.110).aspx). More about how to serialize an object using the `BinaryFormatter` can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4865104/993547).

Comment: GetBytes() then serialize, is that what should I do?

Comment: No, it is serialized already, but it can only serialize a `string`. If you want to serialize another type of object, use `BinaryFormatter`.

Comment: So, GetBytes is basically a serialization of strings?
I currently practicing on making a chat application via socket, 
therefore, GetBytes is enough?

Comment: @MalcolmWho Normally it isn't enough. Depending on the transmission medium, you'll have to write somewhere the length of the encoded string (often you'll prepend it to the string, using `BitConverter.GetBytes(lengthofserializedstring)` to get a `byte[]` and sending it before sending the `byte[]` you received by `Encoding.Default.GetBytes()`). ah... and you should use `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` if possible

Comment: @MalcolmWho: Yes, if that is the only message going around. May I suggest to take a loot at [SignalR](http://signalr.net/)? It uses web sockets to communicate and it providing in a lot of functionality you need.

Comment: I do not agree at all that GetBytes() could be regarded as "special" serialization!

Comment: @MartinMeeser: Want to explain why? From the coder perspective it is.

Comment: @PatrckHofman you really are not aware of the difference? I mean ... from the coder perspective?

Answer (score 1):

In .NET you too have serialization. You have binary serialization, XML serialization and JSON serialization.

With serialization you transform an object to another format in order to store it or to send it over the network. An serialized object can be deserialized to an instance of the object (if the class is available at runtime).

With GetBytes() you get the Byte Representation of a variable at runtime. There is no information about the type.
You could interpret the Bytes as any type you want, creating unuseful results of course. GetBytes() returns the raw bytes as it is stored in your physical memory.

Comment: "With GetBytes() ... There is no information about the type." There is: it is a `string`.

Comment: Yes I see, I have been a little mistaken with BitConverter.GetBytes(), but I think basic idea still holds.

Comment: @Patrick: Within the bytes created by GetBytes(), is there any information that it has to be converted to a string? No it does not. When send over the network to another .NET process, has the the other process any change of detecting which type the bytes should be converted to.

Comment: If there are just strings exchanged, there is no need to.