# How to get byte array in a fuction whose parameters are generic in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, type-conversion, endianness

I want to give `int` or `short` or `Single` or `Double` to the function. And I want an array to be return in reverse order.

Like

- `fun(2.0f)` will return `[0x40, 0, 0, 0]`
- `fun(0x01020304)` will return `[1, 2, 3, 4]`
- `fun( (short) 0x0102)` will return `[1, 2]`

I've tried  [Convert any object to a byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865104/convert-any-object-to-a-byte/18205093)

But I could not achieve my goal. I will be very to learn if this function can be written as generic `<T>` type.

```
public static byte[] fun(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
        return null;
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bf.Serialize(ms, obj);                
        byte[] ar = ms.ToArray();
        Array.Reverse(ar);
        return ar;
    }
}
```

After @InBetween 's answer my code is below and works fine.

```
    public static byte[] Reverse(byte[] ar )
    {
        Array.Reverse(ar);
        return ar;
    }
    Reverse(BitConverter.GetBytes(2.0f);// gives me [0x40, 0, 0, 0] in a single line.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you taken a look at [`BitConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter_members(v=vs.85).aspx)?

That said, generics is not a good fit for methods that take "primitive" types. There is no `T: Primitive` or `T: Numeric` constraint. The best you could do would be `T: struct` but that is a pretty weak effort.

Also, generics means that there should be an infinite number of types valid for a given generic method, thats why its...well, *generic*. If your set of types is finite, and even more so if its just a handful, your are not using the right tool for the job.

So, to wrap it up, if you *do* know the types you need to support, the correct way to solve this is using method overloading, and [`BitConverter.GetBytes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.getbytes(v=vs.85).aspx) does just that.