# Marshal c# struct to C struct is not working

Tags: c#, c, struct, marshalling, unmanaged

I want to call the following C function from C#, but it doesn't work.
The C code is part of the .so file. In my case the code should run in an Linux environment!

The C# Code is part of a console app which uses the .so file

```
/**
* \brief Register a tag callback functions.
* \param callback:  tag callback functions.
* \return None
*/
extern void nfcManager_registerTagCallback(nfcTagCallback_t *callback);
```

Here is the definition of the required parameter:
(C Code)

```
/**
 * \brief NFC Tag callback function structure definition.
 */
typedef struct {
    /**
     * \brief NFC Tag callback function when tag is detected.
     * param pTagInfo       tag infomation
     */
    void (*onTagArrival) (nfc_tag_info_t *pTagInfo);

    /**
     * \brief NFC Tag callback function when tag is removed.
     */
    void (*onTagDeparture) (void);
}nfcTagCallback_t;
```

And this is the defintion of nfc_tag_info_t:
(C Code)

```
/**
 * \brief NFC tag information structure definition.
 */
typedef struct
{
    /**
     *  \brief indicates the technology of tag
     */
    unsigned int technology;
    /**
     *  \brief the handle of tag
     */
    unsigned int handle;
    /**
     *  \brief the uid of tag
     */
    char uid[32];
    /**
     *  \brief the uid length
     */
    unsigned int uid_length;
    /**
     *  \brief activated protocol
     */
    tNFC_PROTOCOL protocol;

}nfc_tag_info_t;
```

I tried the following:
(C# Code)

```
    [DllImport("libnfc_nci_linux.so", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private static extern void nfcManager_registerTagCallback(IntPtr callback);


    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct nfcTagCallback_t
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]
        public IntPtr onTagArrival;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]
        public IntPtr onTagDeparture;
    }

    public static void onArrival(IntPtr intPtr)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Arrival");
    }

    public static void onDeparture()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Departure");
    }

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public delegate void CallbackOnArrival(IntPtr intPtr);
    
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public delegate void CallbackOnDeparture();

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct nfc_tag_info_t
    {
        /**
         *  \brief indicates the technology of tag
         */
        public uint technology;
        /**
         *  \brief the handle of tag
         */
        public uint handle;
        /**
         *  \brief the uid of tag
         */
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 32)]
        public char[] uid;
        /**
         *  \brief the uid length
         */
        public uint uid_length;
        /**
         *  \brief activated protocol
         */
        public byte protocol;

    }
```

I call the method like this:

```
var nfcTagCallback = new nfcTagCallback_t();
nfcTagCallback.onTagDeparture = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(new CallbackOnDeparture(onDeparture));
nfcTagCallback.onTagArrival = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(new CallbackOnArrival(onArrival));

IntPtr testPointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(nfcTagCallback));
Marshal.StructureToPtr(nfcTagCallback, testPointer, true);
nfcManager_registerTagCallback(testPointer); // <-- Exception (see below)
```

If I run this code, the following exception is thrown:

```
Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentException: Type 'PN7150_NFC.Program+nfcTagCallback_t' cannot be marshaled as an unmanaged structure; no meaningful size or offset can be computed.
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOfHelper(Type t, Boolean throwIfNotMarshalable)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf[T](T structure)
   at PN7150_NFC.Program.Main(String[] args) in /home/pi/Desktop/PN7150-NFC/PN7150-NFC/Program.cs:line 95
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1345178

Comment: Is dll c lanaguage or windows?  You are using CallingConvention.StdCall which is windows.

Comment: @jdweng C Language is the dll. But in the case it is a .so file because the program runs in an linux environment

Comment: @Simon : The compiler does not know the OS.  The compiler options are either Windows (standard) or c language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to marshal `IntPtr` as `FunctionPtr`, which [should be used on delegates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.unmanagedtype#system-runtime-interopservices-unmanagedtype-functionptr). You can either:

1. Define `onTagArrival` as `CallbackOnArrival` and `onTagDeparture` as `CallbackOnDeparture`.
2. remove `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]`.

Finally, as @jdweng pointed out in the comments, be careful with the calling convensions.